# How to make my class-based view to work in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My project is about about building a blog software with Django. Everything is working fine in the app, but I read about a class-based view which I didn't fully understand as I am not into OOP. I just wanted to convert all my function-based view to a class-based view, but when I tried it, i got this error

```
  File "C:\Users\De Stone Of David\Desktop\python\second\projects\eblog\blog\views.py", line 146
    def(self, request, **kwargs):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here is the code for the function-based view
views.py

```
def newPost(request):    
    deyCat = Category.objects.all() 
    if request.method =='POST':
        myForm = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        if request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'create_hidden':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            category_id = request.POST.get('category')
            image = request.FILES.get('image') 
            if myForm.is_valid():
                if Posts.objects.create(title=title, content=content, category_id=category_id, image=image, author_id=request.user.id):
                    response_data = {
                        'SType': 'success',
                        'message': "Saved Successfully"
                    }   
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")  
        elif request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'category_hidden':
            CatNames = request.POST.getlist('CatName[]')
            for CatName in CatNames:
                Category.objects.get_or_create(CatName=CatName)
            response_data = {
                'SType': 'success',
                'message': "Saved Successfully"
            }                
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

    context={
        'form':NewPostForm(),
        'title':'Create Post',
        'category': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/form.html', context)
```

here is the code for the class-based view
views.py

```
class NewPostView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/form.html'
    deyCat = Category.objects.all()

    def(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': NewPostForm(),
            'title': 'Create Post',
            'category': self.deyCat
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        myForm = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        if request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'create_hidden':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            category_id = request.POST.get('category')
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            if myForm.is_valid():
                if Posts.objects.create(title=title, content=content, category_id=category_id, image=image,
                                        author_id=request.user.id):
                    response_data = {
                        'SType': 'success',
                        'message': "Saved Successfully"
                    }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
        elif request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'category_hidden':
            CatNames = request.POST.getlist('CatName[]')
            for CatName in CatNames:
                Category.objects.get_or_create(CatName=CatName)
            response_data = {
                'SType': 'success',
                'message': "Saved Successfully"
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

pls, how can I solve this error message or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You define a function without setting it a name.

Comment: give function `def(self, request, **kwargs):` a name like this `def get(self, request, **kwargs):`

Comment: pls but how can i sanitize the data from the form before sending it to database

Comment: For any further questions, please close this one and open another one.

Comment: yes you can sanitize the form. it depends on the kind of check and validations that you wants to perform otherwise in production your site will be messed up. Like Aurelien stated, tis question is out of the scope of the post. You can open a new question and see who cares to help. am also here for you

Answer (score 0):

You should give your function a name, before passing it arguments.

Instead of `def(self, request, **kwargs)` you should write `def my_function(self, request, **kwargs)`